# Match 2 where clauses in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

Say I have a database with an organisation that can belong to 1 or more wards and each ward to 1 or more sectors. Now I want a query that displays other organisations that belong to the same sectors in the same wards. I pass the query a `varchar` containing the id's, comma delimited. Then I have a function that splits these id's:

```
WHERE
    ess.SPEAKER_SECTOR_ID IN (SELECT s.item FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@P_Sectors, ',') s)
    AND w.WARD_ID IN (SELECT s.item FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@P_Wards, ',') s)
```

Problem is, this returns all the sectors that the organisation belongs to and all the wards it's in. Eg:

Say this organisation has the following wards/sectors:

> Ward | Sector
>   59   | ARTS AND CULTURE 
>   71 | BUSINESS 
>   72 | SAFETY AND SECURITY ORGANISATIONS

This for instance will display organisations in ward 59 and sector BUSINESS, even though the current organisation does not belong to the BUSINESS sector in ward 59 but only in ward 71.

---

**EDIT:** Well, the database is pretty convoluted and unchangeable because some legacy delphi application apparently still uses it. I'm working in ASP.NET. Just some of the relevant tables are as follows:

[image: DB Structure]

---

**EDIT:** Let me clarify with this visual example. Multiple wards and sectors can indeed be added for any organisation. The wards and sectors added in this example organisation:

[image]

Now I want my query to return *other* organisations that are both in the same ward and for that ward in the same sector that the above example organisation is in. At the moment, my where clause returns organisations that are in the same sectors and that are in the same wards separately:

[image]

This is incorrect. Both the ward **and** sector should match for the other organisations that are displayed. For instance, only organisations that are in ward 59 and for ward 59 in sector ARTS AND CULTURE. At the moment BUSINESS for ward 59 is displayed because the example organisation has business in ward 71.

Comment: Can you show us your database structure?

Comment: @Arion: Extract of the database structure provided

Comment: I have been reading you question again and again... I don't get it. Do you want to get the unique connections from organisation to sector and ward? I mean you database structure basically tells me that the same org can have multiple connections to the same ward and sector

Comment: @Arion: I apologize for seeming ambiguous. Hope it's now a bit clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear but I guess that it is because you place these conditions on different tables.
You should place this condition on the only one table: `ELEC_INTEREST_WARD`

```
SELECT o.* FROM ORGANISATION o
JOIN ELEC_INTEREST_GROUP ON EIG ON O.Org_id=EIG.Org_id
JOIN ELEC_INTEREST_WARD ON EIW ON EIG.INTEREST_GROUP_ID=EIW.INTEREST_GROUP_ID
WHERE 
     EIW.SPEAKER_SECTOR_ID IN 
                      (SELECT s.item FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@P_Sectors, ',') s)
    AND 
     EIW.WARD_ID IN 
                      (SELECT s.item FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@P_Wards, ',') s)
```

The other way is to use only `INTEREST_WARD_ID` list paramenter to get exact pairs not WARD and SECTORS separated lists.